How to set task return values?
Snowflake allows for return values for tasks, as can be seen in this screenshot (from the documentation):

How do I set these return values?
I have tried it like this:
create or replace task BI_ELT.LOGS.TEST1_TSK
schedule='USING CRON 0 4 * * * Europe/Berlin'
as 
BEGIN 
SELECT 1;
RETURN 'One selected';
END;

But the "Run History" of the task still shows no return value.

In the "Query Details" however I can see the result:

How do I get return values in the task graph table (like in the first screen shot)?
All hints are appreciated!

You are searching for SYSTEM$SET_RETURN_VALUE:

In a task graph, a task can call this function to set a return value. Another task that identifies this task as the predecessor task (using the AFTER keyword in the task definition) can retrieve the return value set by the predecessor task using SYSTEM$GET_PREDECESSOR_RETURN_VALUE.

create or replace task BI_ELT.LOGS.TEST1_TSK
schedule='USING CRON 0 4 * * * Europe/Berlin'
as 
BEGIN 
  SELECT 1;
  CALL SYSTEM$SET_RETURN_VALUE('One selected');
END;

Output:


Ah, that indeed works, thanks so much!

Interestingly, the "Results" section in the Query Details says "null" now. It seems that the RETURN statement goes into the "Results" while the SYSTEM$SET_RETURN_VALUE goes into the "Return Value".
